# Change cell color to match adjacent cell's conditional format

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I am working on a front end to easily view data on a calendar. The data is pulled from a second table on a different workbook. I have pulled the data over from the source table, and can conditionally format the actual values, but the calendar dates cannot have the same conditional formatting applied. Only having half of each date in the calendar be formatted is incredibly unappealing, and I am looking to make the top cell of each pair match the bottom cell.

[image: Image of calendar]

Since the conditional formatting is a mask, an attempt to copy cell color by VBA was unsuccessful. Using the code `Range("I2").Interior.Color = Range("I3").Interior.Color` changes the color of `I2` to match the color of `I3`, which has no background color, due to how Excel handles the conditional format.

**There are two alternative solutions**, but I am looking to avoid them:

1. I can apply a series of single conditional format to the cells containing
   the date value and manually create the gradient effect. This does lose
   some of the effect of the 3 color gradient however in that it is
   slightly slower to at a glance differentiate between cells.
2. I can use VBA to manually calculate the color that should be applied
   to each cell. While this would have the same effect as what I am
   looking for, I expect the calculations and coding to take longer
   than desired for a simple project.

---

Is there a way to apply the conditional formatting below to cells that are only adjacent to the values?

[image: Conditional format applied]

Edit/ The desired formatting would look like this, except it would be calculated and not manually applied:

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think solution 2 is your best choice :/

Comment: @findwindow - I added an image to clarify what I was looking to accomplish, if that's what you were referencing with 'understanding correctly'. I appreciate the second opinion, even if it does confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know if the original question asked is possible, I have completed alternative solution #2:

> Use VBA to manually calculate the color that should be applied to each cell.

On the calendar page I added a button (form control), and created a macro to run on click. The macro updates the calculation table - which controls the daily values displayed - with the input value and then calculates the gradient color required for the top half of the calendar square. The current spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Finished screenshot]

**I kept the conditional formatting to color the bottom half of the square, but it can also be handled from the VBA side.**

The code for the button macro is as follows;

```
Sub loadDetails_Click()

Dim area1colMin As Integer
Dim area1colMax As Integer
Dim area2colMin As Integer
Dim area2colMax As Integer
Dim rowMin As Integer
Dim rowMax As Integer

area1colMin = 6
area1colMax = 12
area2colMin = 14
area2colMax = 20
rowMin = 3
rowMax = 29

' Insert input value into calculation spreadsheet, making sure
' values/conditional formatting calculation waits until the code is ran.

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VBACalcPage").Range("A6").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SingleItemLookup").Range("C1").Value

colorArea area1colMin, area1colMax, rowMin, rowMax
colorArea area2colMin, area2colMax, rowMin, rowMax

End Sub
```

The macro calls the function `colorArea()` twice;

```
Public Function colorArea(minC As Integer, maxC As Integer, minR As Integer, maxR As Integer)

Dim tempCellValue As Integer
Dim cnstPosR As Integer
Dim cnstPosG As Integer
Dim cnstPosB As Integer
Dim cnstNegR As Integer
Dim cnstNegG As Integer
Dim cnstNegB As Integer
Dim colorTempRed As Integer
Dim colorTempGreen As Integer
Dim colorTempBlue As Integer
Dim intPosCap As Integer
Dim intNegCap As Integer
Dim colorPushRed As Integer
Dim colorPushGreen As Integer
Dim colorPushBlue As Integer


cnstPosR = 79
cnstPosG = 129
cnstPosB = 189
cnstNegR = 192
cnstNegG = 80
cnstNegB = 77
intPosCap = 1000
intNegCap = -1000

For column = minC To maxC
    For row = minR To maxR
        If row Mod 2 = 1 Then
            tempCellValue = Cells(row, column).Value
            If tempCellValue > 0 Then
                colorTempRed = cnstPosR
                colorTempGreen = cnstPosG
                colorTempBlue = cnstPosB
            Else
                colorTempRed = cnstNegR
                colorTempGreen = cnstNegG
                colorTempBlue = cnstNegB
            End If
            If tempCellValue > 1000 Then tempCellValue = 1000
            If tempCellValue < -1000 Then tempCellValue = -1000

            colorPushRed = 255 - ((255 - colorTempRed) * Abs(tempCellValue / 1000))
            colorPushGreen = 255 - ((255 - colorTempGreen) * Abs(tempCellValue / 1000))
            colorPushBlue = 255 - ((255 - colorTempBlue) * Abs(tempCellValue / 1000))

            Cells(row - 1, column).Interior.Color = RGB(colorPushRed, colorPushGreen, colorPushBlue)
        End If
    Next row
Next column

End Function
```